# Unittest saveorupdate-method on a repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I'm writing unittests. I'm using Moq and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.

I have the following already in place and working:

```
 Mock<PersonRepository> _persoonRepository;
    IEnumerable<Domain.Person> _personen;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // *Arrange*
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Domain.Person>>();
        var mockContext = new Mock<DatabaseContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Persons).Returns(mockSet.Object);
        _persoonRepository = new Moq.Mock<PersonRepository>(mockContext.Object);
        _personen = new List<Domain.Person>() { new Domain.Person { ID = 1, Name = "Bart Schelkens", GewerkteDagen = 200, Leeftijd = 52, Type = "1" },
                                        new Domain.Person { ID = 2, Name = "Yoram Kerckhofs", GewerkteDagen = 190, Leeftijd = 52, Type = "1" }};

        _persoonRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(_personen);

    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetAllShouldReturnResult()
    {
        var result = _persoonRepository.Object.GetAll();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

Now I would like to test my add method as well.

My repository has a method SaveOrUpdate which takes two parameters a person of type Person and a string.

I can't seem to get my test in place.
Can anyone help me?

The method on my repository looks as follows :

```
 public virtual void SaveOrUpdatePersoon(Person persoon, string userName)
    {
        using (DbContextTransaction transactionScope = DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
                DbContext.Persons.AddOrUpdate(persoon);
                DbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should really try to provide more info of what you are trying to do.
To me it seems like you're not really testing anything with your test. You're testing your mocking is working, which I guess is not your intention.

Are you trying to test that you repository interacts with the DatabaseContext?
If so you should use Verify on the mocked DatabaseContext instead. To being able to help you please provide more info.

Try something like this

```
    Persoon p = new Domain.Person { ID = 1}
_persoonRepository = new PersonRepository(mockContext.Object);
_persoonRepository.SaveOrUpdatePersoon(p, 2);
mockContext.Verify(x => x.Persons.SaveOrUpdate(p), Times.Once)
```

Here's an alternative to making SaveOrUpdate virtual

```
[Test]
        public void Method()
        {
            Person p = new Person {Id = 1};
            var mockSet = new Mock<IPersons>();
            var mockContext = new Mock<DatabaseContext>();
            mockContext.Setup(m => m.Persons).Returns(mockSet.Object);
            var repository = new Repository(mockContext.Object);
            repository.SaveOrUpdatePerson(p, 2);
            mockSet.Verify(x => x.SaveOrUpdate(p, 2), Times.Once);
        }


        public class Repository
        {
            private DatabaseContext databaseContext;

            public Repository(DatabaseContext databaseContext)
            {
                this.databaseContext = databaseContext;
            }

            public void SaveOrUpdatePerson(Person p, int id)
            {
                databaseContext.Persons.SaveOrUpdate(p, id);
            }
        }

        public class DatabaseContext
        {
            public virtual IPersons Persons { get; set; }
        }

        public interface IPersons
        {
            // add whatever else needed here
            void SaveOrUpdate(ModelJsonSerializationTest.Person p, int id);
        }

        public class Persons : IPersons
        {
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
            public void SaveOrUpdate(Person p, int  id)
            {
                if (persons.Any(x => x.Id == id)) // whatever you are using id for
                { //Do update here
                }
                else
                {
                    persons.Add(p);
                }
            }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: I want to test my interaction with the databasecontext but without actually writing anything in my database. I was following an example that I found.

Comment: I suppose you repository is a wrapper then and that you want to test that your repository interacts with the databasecontext. Since I do not know your exact methods I will provide an example how to do it. mockContext .Verify(x => x.MethodToVerifyInteraction(It.IsAny<T>), Times.Once) and then call the same method on your repository.

Comment: Indeed my repository is a wrapper to my databasecontext :
 public virtual void SaveOrUpdatePersoon(Person persoon, string userName)
        {
                    DbContext.Persons.AddOrUpdate(persoon);
                    DbContext.SaveChanges();
            }

Comment: I've tried your sample, but i'm getting the error : Invalid verify on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Persons.AddOrUpdate<Person>(new[] { .p })
The method on my repository is virtual.

Comment: It does not help if your repository is virtual, your not mocking the repository. It's AddOrUpdate that has to be virtual. I would on the other hand not change that, I would make Person and other models/entities implement IUpdateable interface that you could mock instead. You could mock DataContext.Person to return a mocked IUpdateable that you do your verify on.